# Is it possible to find out if a file has completed downloading from my API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on a project where I'm allowing downloads of ZIP files. I need to track how many and who has downloaded my ZIP file. I have written the following controller method:

```
[HttpPost("DownloadDesign")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileStreamResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public IActionResult DownloadDesign([FromBody] RequestDto requestDto)
{
    try
    {
        string artPackFilePath = ""; //building my file path here
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(artPackFilePath))
        {
            //I can update the request count here by updating it in database before serving my file
            return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(artPackFilePath), "application/zip");
        }
        else
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Requested design is not available");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Download failed");
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I can find out who requested the file from the `RequestDto` and also update the request count. But is it possible to find out if the file transfer was complete in this API? I need to track if the download was partial or complete. Is something like this possible from my end?

Comment: Probably not, unless you also control the downloading client (so you can signal the download having completed to the server).

Comment: Yes, just not in the action itself. The file transfer is performed by the `FileResult` object returned by `File()` or more specifically, the [FileStreamResultExecutor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.filestreamresultexecutor?view=aspnetcore-5.0) it uses. That class is registered in the DI container as an `IActionResultExecutor<FileStreamResult>`. You can replace it with your own implementation which overrides `WriteFileAsync` and logs *something* when it finishes.

Comment: I think it's possible if you create your own `FileResult`. I mean, by this way, you can control how to write content to response stream.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you point me to resources on how to do that?

Comment: @AKX I cannot control the Client. But I can ask the Client to call another API to update the download status. I want to keep it as an last option.

Comment: You won't be able to know definitively whether the client has successfully downloaded the file over http unless you control the client as well.  This is due to how HTTP and networking in general works.  Think of sending a piece of mail, you won't know whether someone received it unless they explicitly tell you.  You can approximate it by seeing whether the server has iterated through all bytes of the message and ensure they're provided to the underlying network stream, but there will be edge cases.